# Perlbrew libs management

Tags: perl, ubuntu, perlbrew, cpanm

I have installed perlbrew and installed two Perls with it.
Now I am trying to separate libraries for modules I install with cpanm.

I want (if possible) to switch to one Perl (within Perlbrew) (for example: 5.22.4) and once I call `cpanm install Some::Module` the module will be installed in the separate library, related only to this Perl.

Then, in the script, I would like to have like the example below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use Some::Module;
print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
print "Works!";
```

and that's it. No any other `use lib 'path';` or so.
I tried to use `perlbrew lib create perl-5.22.4@somename` and then switch to it.

Then call `cpanm install Some::Module` and I see the result at the location `~/.perlbrew/perl-5.22.4@somename/lib/perl5/Some/Module.pm`, but when I call my script from a browser I see `Error 500` and the logs say `"missing module Some::Module, check @INC etc..."`

What I also found that if I move the `~/.perlbrew/perl-5.22.4@somename/lib/perl5/Some/Module.pm` to `~/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.4/lib/5.22.4/Some/Module.pm` or to `/home/arseniigorkin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.4/lib/site_perl/5.22.4/x86_64-linux/Some/Module.pm` then the script works. And Perl 5.22.4 (in our example) has its own library without need to use `use lib 'path';`

But, how to set up Perlbrew to switch cpanm automatically to this directory?

What I was also trying: `cpanm install -l /home/arseniigorkin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.4/lib/site_perl/5.22.4/x86_64-linux Some::Module` to specify the target lib dir, but it creates the next tree under `/home/arseniigorkin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.4/lib/site_perl/5.22.4/x86_64-linux` instead:

- lib

  - perl5

    - Some

      - Module.pm
    - x86_64-linux

      - auto

        - [.....]
      - .meta

        - [.....]
      - perllocal.pod
    - install.pm
- man

  - man3

    - [.....]

and, sadly, the script throws `Error 500`.

So, is there a possibility to omit `use lib 'path';` in the script, switching between multiple Perl versions in Perlbrew?

This all happens on Ubuntu 22.04.

**Update**:

When switching to perl-5.22.4@somename and installing Some::Module via cpanm the module appears under the `~/.perlbrew/perl-5.22.4@somename/lib/perl5/Some/Module.pm` as mentioned above, but the CGI script fails with Error 500.

However, when I execute the next command: `perlbrew list-modules` it shows Some::Module as installed under the current Perl (which I am switched to). So, this is a dissonance: Perlbrew "sees" the module under the specific Perl, but the CGI script cannot "see" this module under the same Perl.

**Update 2**:

here is the output of the `perlbrew info:`

```
Current perl:
  Name: perl-5.22.4@somename
  Path: /home/username/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.4/bin/perl
  Config: -de -Dprefix=/home/username/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.4 -Dusesitecustomize -Aeval:scriptdir=/home/username/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.4/bin
  Compiled at: Nov 10 2022 23:26:53

perlbrew:
  version: 0.96
  ENV:
    PERLBREW_ROOT: /home/username/perl5/perlbrew
    PERLBREW_HOME: /home/username/.perlbrew
    PERLBREW_PATH: /home/username/.perlbrew/libs/perl-5.22.4@somename/bin:/home/username/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/home/arseniigorkin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.4/bin
    PERLBREW_MANPATH: /home/username/.perlbrew/libs/perl-5.22.4@somename/man:/home/username/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.4/man
```

**Update 3**:

The dirs permissions for the libs:
[image]
and
[image]

`@terry0its` is the name of the library (in the example I called it `@somename`.

Update 4:

Printing vars:

- `PERL_MB_OPT`
- `PERL_MM_OPT`
- `PERL5LIB`
- `PATH`
- `PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT`

with the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
print <<HTML;
Vars:<br>
PERL_MB_OPT = @{[$ENV{"PERL_MB_OPT"}]}<br>
PERL_MM_OPT = @{[$ENV{"PERL_MM_OPT"}]}<br>
PERL5LIB = @{[$ENV{"PERL5LIB"}]}<br>
PATH = @{[$ENV{"PATH"}]}<br>
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT = @{[$ENV{"PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT"}]}<br>
HTML
```

1. In the web browser:

*Vars*:

`PERL_MB_OPT` =

`PERL_MM_OPT` =

`PERL5LIB` =

`PATH` = /home/username/.perlbrew/libs/perl-5.22.4@terry0its/bin:/home/username/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/home/username/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.4/bin:/root/Komodo IDE/bin:/home/username/anaconda3/condabin:/root/Komodo IDE/bin:/home/username/pycharm/bin:/home/username/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/home/username/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts

`PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT` =

2. With the terminal:

> Content-type:text/html
>
> Vars:
>
> `PERL_MB_OPT` = --install_base
> /home/username/.perlbrew/libs/perl-5.22.4@terry0its
>
> `PERL_MM_OPT` =
> INSTALL_BASE=/home/username/.perlbrew/libs/perl-5.22.4@terry0its
>
> `PERL5LIB` =
> /home/username/.perlbrew/libs/perl-5.22.4@terry0its/lib/perl5
>
> `PATH` =
> /home/username/.perlbrew/libs/perl-5.22.4@terry0its/bin:/home/username/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/home/username/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.4/bin:/root/Komodo
> IDE/bin:/home/username/anaconda3/condabin:/root/Komodo
> IDE/bin:/home/username/pycharm/bin:/home/username/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/home/username/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts
>
> `PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT` =
> /home/username/.perlbrew/libs/perl-5.22.4@terry0its

**Update 5**:

When I switch to a pure perl-5.22.4 (without external lib, like @terry0its) I see the next output for the same scripts (after the restart of the server):

1. In the web browser:

*Vars*:

`PERL_MB_OPT` =

`PERL_MM_OPT` =

`PERL5LIB` =

`PATH` = /home/username/anaconda3/condabin:/home/username/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/home/username/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.4/bin:/root/Komodo IDE/bin:/home/arseniigorkin/perl5/bin:/home/username/pycharm/bin:/home/username/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/home/username/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts

`PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT` =

2. With the terminal:

> Content-type:text/html
>
> Vars:
>
> `PERL_MB_OPT` --install_base "/home/username/perl5"
>
> `PERL_MM_OPT` = INSTALL_BASE=/home/username/perl5
>
> `PERL5LIB` =
>
> `PATH` =
> /home/username/anaconda3/condabin:/home/username/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/home/username/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.4/bin:/root/Komodo IDE/bin:/home/username/perl5/bin:/home/username/pycharm/bin:/home/username/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/home/username/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts
>
> `PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT` =
> /home/username/perl5

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249559/discussion-on-question-by-arsenii-perlbrew-libs-management).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to *Apache2* server-specific behavior with ENV variables.

It strips off some environment variables so they are undefined in your CGI scripts.

To have them in the CGI script you simply have to add `PassEnv PERL5LIB` into your host conf file and restart the server. Then, voila - you have `PERL5LIB` showing correctly in the output of `$ENV{PERL5LIB}` all across your site.

The example code:

```
<Directory "/home/user/someproject/server/www/public_html/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options None
    Require all granted
    Options +ExecCGI
    PassEnv PERL5LIB
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
</Directory>
```

So, to use Perlbrew and easily switching between Perls and to have automatically handling all your libs (incl. externally created with `perlbrew create lib somename`) you have to *PASS* the `PERl5LIB` environment to your CGI scripts explicitly in the Apache configuration file for your host.

Do not forget to check if your mod_env is enabled in the httpd.conf (main Apache configuration file) as `LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so` (it must be uncommented).

I hope it will help others to handle easily their Perl libraries of perlbrew with Apache2 server.

Also, the module [mod_env](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_env.html) allows us to add custom environment variables, that we will be able to use all across the host or a server (it depends on where you put it in - inside the *main conf* file, your *host file*, or just into `.htaccess` for a particular dir(s) or even page(s)).

Comment: The cgi script in the question will end up using the first `perl` in Apache's PATH, which is going to be the system `perl` under normal circumstances. /// Your solution also relies on `PERL5LIB` being set to something in Apache process, but you didn't show this, and you didn't say to what it should be set.

Answer (score 0):

`perlbrew` does two things:

- Makes installing Perl a little bit easier.
- Manipulate the PATH of a shell that loads it.

The CGI script isn't launched by a shell.

---

First, you shouldn't be using `PERL5LIB`. Why install a custom `perl` using `perlbrew` and then try to cause it to use modules installed by another `perl`? This is nothing but bad. Unset `PERL5LIB`.

And with `PERL5LIB` unset, you shouldn't be using `PERL_MB_OPT` and `PERL_MM_OPT` either. You need to let the modules get installed where `perl` will find them.

So start by cleaning out the mess. Make sure `PERL5LIB`, `PERL_MB_OPT` and `PERL_MM_OPT` aren't set anywhere. You may to need reinstall the modules if they were installed in a weird place.

Now, using the correct `perl` will load the modules installed by that `perl`.

---

So what left is ensuring that we're using the correct `perl`. You use `/usr/bin/env` to locate `perl`. Does it makes sense for Apache's PATH to control which `perl` your application uses? Probably not.

What I would do is create an alias in perlbrew for your project.

```bash
perlbrew alias create perl-5.22.4@somename myproject
```

Then use the following shebang line:

```perl
#!/home/username/perl5/perlbrew/perls/myproject/bin/perl
```

That will allow you use to control which build of `perl` your project uses using

```bash
perlbrew alias create -f ... myproject
```

This works using symlinks, not PATH manipulation, so it works from anywhere, not just shells using `perlbrew`.